# ReferenceError: _ is not defined while using angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm getting `ReferenceError: _ is not defined` the [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)

I don't really understand why I'm getting this error, because I'm doing exactly what it is written on the website.

Also I searched for similar questions, but they didn't helped.

**bundle.js**

```
$ = window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./lib/jquery');
require('./lib/angular-simple-logger.js');
require('./lib/angular-google-maps.js');
require('./lib/lodash.js');
```

I'm importind `bundle.js` into the `index.html`. I also tried to use `ngLodash`, but no results.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngLodash',
  'nemLogging',
  'uiGmapgoogle-maps'
]);

app.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
       key: '{myKey}',
       v: '3.20',
       libraries: 'places' // I don't need the whole map, only the places
   });
});
```

Also I enabled the `GoogleMaps Api` from the `Google Developer Console`

Does someone have some experience with this library and can give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the _ [underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore) library as a dependency. `npm install underscore`, or add to your bower config, or whatever you use for dependecy management.

```
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I even added underscore as a dependency using maven, but still getting the same error. Can anyone please help me out?